# How can I apply node scaling per group of nodes in a network? Visjs library

Tags: javascript

Is this possible to do in a network graph using [vis.js](http://visjs.org) library? If yes then please show me an example. From what I understand, scaling is  for the entire network and can't be done per group basis.

Comment: Please add a link to visjs. And add it to your headline as this question is not related to plain javascript and what do you mean by scaling? Is it visual scaling or scaling for performance or what do you scale?

Answer (score 0):

In the [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) library [nodes](http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html) are scaled, based on each nodes value. Possibly you can find all nodes in a group and set their value to scale them up. Read the docs about node scaling.

Comment: I have read the docs about node scaling and all you can do is provide scaling : { min, max}  In node options. If I have a group with values 1,2,3...10 and another group with values 100,200,300....10000 then then the node scaling will make the nodes in second group way bigger than the ones in group one which I don't want as these groups are not similar in concept

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Values of nodes are just used to scale nodes. The value field of a group is a simple inheritance field that affects the contained nodes. There is no other concept for values.